# Find float in a text string without leading 0

Tags: python, regex, floating-point

I am trying to capture float numbers (using Python 3) from a text string like this:

`.31 [0.25-0.37] m2 incr`

and this is working well for numbers on the format 0.45 if I use the following code:

```
import re
re.findall("\d+.\d+", ".31 [0.25-0.37] m2 incr")
```

But if the null is missing, like .31, the number is not copied. I have tried some variations of this but without success; can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: replace `\d+.\d+` with `\d*\.\d+`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close...

```
re.findall("\d*\.\d+", ".31 [0.25-0.37] m2 incr")
```

You don't know if you have a leading digit, so you should use `*` instead of `+`, and you should escape the dot.